# should I create a global buffer in C

Tags: c, scanf, buffer, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>

char buffer[2048];

int main()
{
    int a;

    do {
        printf("Enter an integer: ");
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", &a) < 1)
            printf("Invalid input\n");
    } while (sscanf(buffer, "%d", &a) < 1);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to use `fgets` and `sscanf` to read input from the user is creating a global buffer good practice?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to avoid defining buffer in main?

Comment: yes i  want to use it for all functions

Comment: Then making it global seems fine, as long as all the functions which use it are also defined in the same .c file. If multiple files need access, then you'll need to declare buffer in a header too.

Comment: I'd say best practice is avoiding global variables.

Comment: How would I be able to create a buffer for all functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is creating a global buffer good practice?

The best practice is to limit the scope of objects (aka variables) as much as possible. That kind of translates to "Global variables should be avoided if the task can be solved equally good with variables with smaller scope"

So before introducing a global you should ask yourself: Why? What problem are you solving by introducing a global?

The information in your question doesn't tell us why you want the global `buffer` instead of just defining a local `buffer` when you need one.

On modern computers it's normally not a problem to define a 2K buffer inside a function. There is normally no performance penalty involved. There is normally no memory problem involved (as typical stack sizes are much larger).

So with the information given in the question, the answer is: "It's bad practice - don't use a global".

**OT:**

It's probably not relevant for the real question but your code is rather strange as you call `sscanf` twice on the same buffer. To avoid that you can do:

```
while(1) {
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == NULL) exit(1);
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", &a) == 1) break;
    printf("Invalid input\n");
};
```